# perl getopt::Long path to file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to open an input file as an argument using the Getopt::Long module

This is the beginning of my script

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -s
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);;

my $input='';

GetOptions('input|in=s'    => \$input);

open(my $table1,'<', $input) or die "$! - [$input]"; #input file
```

And this is how I launch the script

```
$ script.pl -in /path/to/file.txt
```

I get as output:

> No such file or directory - [] at script.pl line 13.

Line 13 is the line with `open(...`.

Is there a mistake in the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Perl's built-in option parsing with the `-s` in your shebang line. In a command like `script.pl -in /path/to/file.txt` that makes perl set the variable `$in` to 1 and remove the corresponding entry from `@ARGV` before `Getopt::Long` ever sees it

Just remove `-s` from the shebang line and everything it will work for you

Comment: Yes! But I think it's a combination of this, plus my answer.

Comment: @simbabque: Nope. Without `-s` `Getopt::Long` works fine whether you put the options before or after input file name

Comment: The input filename is one of the options here. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @simbabque: I'm saying that if you can write `script -p1=v1 filename -p2=v2` then `Getopt::Long` will happily pick up both `p1` and `p2`. If you use a `--` then it will stop scanning for any options after it.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, there is no mistake in the script. Your code is doing what you told it to do.

It's calling the `die "$! - [$input]";` part of that line, because the `open` returned a *false* value.

*No such file or directory* is the content of `$!`. That's the error it encountered. And between the `[]` there is the value of `$input`, which is empty. So there's your problem. You're passing an empty string to `open`, and that fails.

**You are calling it the wrong way.**

Getopt::Long requires options that are longer than one letter to be prefixed by `--`. This means that `-in` should be `--in`.

```
$ script.pl --in /path/to/file.txt
```

Because you didn't do that, Getopt::Long didn't see your option, and didn't parse it. A bit higher you initialized `$input = ''`, so it stayed the empty string.

You could add a check to make sure that the input file is always provided.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);;

my $input = '';

GetOptions('input|in=s'  => \$input);

die 'the --input option is required!' unless $input;

open(my $table1,'<', $input) or die "$! - [$input]"; #input file
```

Comment: *"Getopt::Long needs -- at the beginning of the options"* Only if you put `-s` in the command (shebang) line!

Comment: @borodin Hu? The docs don't say that. There's no mention of `-s` in there at all. Only an example that uses an option `-s` to show whitespace in the options.

Comment: That's because the `--` only serves to switch *off* Perl's built-in option processing. Without it an option is parsed and removed from `@ARGV` so `Getopt::Long` never even sees it. So you can use `-s ... --` or not use `-s` at all.

Comment: Updated the line in question for clarity. (I did not verify whether it's true or not. The other answer implies it's not. It might also vary by system. But claiming that Getopt::Long simple ignores `-in`? I strongly doubt that!)